# pandas adding columns values from other rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Assuming I have the dataset

```
   ID cond  press  metrics
0  h1  new     30      1.2
1  h2  old     30      1.0
2  h3  new     50      1.5
3  h4  old     50      1.4
4  h5  new     70      1.8
```

I want to add another column called `ratios`, which is the ratio between the same `ID` & `press` with `cond` old/new. If pairs not found, fill the value with zero.
The final results will be:

```
   ID cond  press  metrics   ratios
0  h1  new     30      1.2  1.0/1.2
1  h2  old     30      1.0        0
2  h3  new     50      1.5  1.4/1.5
3  h4  old     50      1.4        0
4  h5  new     70      1.8        0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ratios = (df.groupby('press')
            .apply(lambda x: (x.loc[x.cond.eq('old'), 'metrics'].squeeze()
                             /x.loc[x.cond.eq('new'), 'metrics'].squeeze()) 
                             if set(x.cond) == {'new', 'old'} else 0))
ratios.name = 'ratios'
df.loc[df.cond.eq('new'), 'ratios'] = df[df.cond.eq('new')].merge(ratios, left_on='press', right_index=True)
df.ratios = df.ratios.fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
   ID cond  press  metrics    ratios
0  h1  new     30      1.2  0.833333
1  h2  old     30      1.0  0.000000
2  h3  new     50      1.5  0.933333
3  h4  old     50      1.4  0.000000
4  h5  new     70      1.8  0.000000
```

Comment: This is nice & should be accepted with an edit to replace the ones with zeros: `df['ratio'] = pd.merge_asof(df, df, on='press', tolerance=0).eval('metrics_y / metrics_x').replace(1, 0)`

Comment: @fishmulch updated with a more robust method that *explicitly* does what OP asked for~

Comment: work exactly as I expect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
old = df[df.cond.eq('old')].reset_index(drop=True).copy()
new = df[df.cond.eq('new')].reset_index(drop=True).copy()

new['metrics'] = pd.merge_asof(old, new, on='press', tolerance=0).eval('metrics_x / metrics_y')

new.fillna(0, inplace=True)
old['metrics'] = 0

final = pd.concat([new, old]).sort_values('ID').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Which gives:

```
>>> final

   ID cond  press   metrics
0  h1  new     30  0.833333
1  h2  old     30  0.000000
2  h3  new     50  0.933333
3  h4  old     50  0.000000
4  h5  new     70  0.000000
```

It's a few lines but easily could be a function. Will leave that to you!